# with one input value change other input field value

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

In the `input` field the text is not printed. Please help me on this issue. I have only basic knowledge on JS

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
```

```html
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<input type="text" id="demo" style="height: 200px"></input>
```

Comment: `input` elements have a `value` property, not `innerHTML`.

Comment: if you want to output data, then you should actually use `<output>` (which uses the value attribute too). Last but not least, `<input>` is an empty tag and as such has no closing tag. As such it also can't have an `innerHTML` or `textContent`